# C# WPF Library creating

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF project. I want to use this project in other new projects using a .DLL file, Like MessageBox form in C#, when we use MessageBox.Show to create a form.

Library project file cannot specify ApplicationDefinition element.

When i change the output of the project to "Class Library", the "InitializeComponent();" method makes an error, so does many other methods in the constructor of my window, saying
The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context
How do i solve this? and how do i use my library once created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply port it to a Class Library. You can hack at the app.xaml and so forth, but it would be best if you create a new "WPF User Control Library" or "WPF Custom Control Library". Migrate over your existing code to it. Make sure to expose Public classes and methods that you wish to call from outside of the library.

You can create a Solution to contain your new library as well as a test WPF Application. That way you can add a reference in the application pointing to your library project. Testing would be easier that way.

As far as how to use the library -- you'll need to do some research on that. There are a number of ways to go about it depending on your needs.

Comment: a user control isn't what i want... i did say i want a MessageBox window

Comment: You tagged this with WPF, therefore that is what you want. Otherwise you'd be taking a generic class library (which is meant for business objects and the like) and merging it in with a WPF application. The financial trading platform I'm working on has such a structure, including custom ViewModels, Views, and Controls. If you wish to have just a generic Class Library, you can do so, but you'll still need to migrate the code. You can't just change the type. You should research how to create such a library, and then post a specific problem you are having if you're unable to work it out. :-)

Answer (score 1):

OK, the problem is that you project is an app, not a library. Just changing it to library in settings wont help.

The best this to do is to create a new project of type 'user control library', and then copy all of your xaml and classes over to the new project

Answer (score 0):

Deleting `App.xaml` from my project worked.